# How to get the value from angular material checkbox

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material2

I have a list of checkboxes:

```
    <section *ngFor="let item of list">
      <mat-checkbox [checked]="item.value" (click)="toggle(_checkbox_value_here_)">{{item.key}}</mat-checkbox>
    </section>
```

I need to pass the `checkbox` value (`_checkbox_value_here_`) to my function, how would you do that?

I can see this related question [How to get checkbox data in angular material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407776/how-to-get-checkbox-data-in-angular-material) but really is there a way go achieve that without using `ngModel` and `reactive forms`?

Comment: this value `_value_` ?

Comment: @SergioEscudero just modified the question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> The click event on the checkbox is just the native click event, which
> doesn't know anything about the checkbox itself. Using the change
> event or just getting a handle on the MatCheckbox instance directly
> (e.g. with @ViewChildren) would be the recommended approach.
>
> (c) https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/13156#issuecomment-427193381

```
<section *ngFor="let item of list">
  <mat-checkbox [checked]="item.value" (change)="toggle($event)">{{item.key}}</mat-checkbox>
</section>
```

Answer (score 9):

you may use the element's `checked` property.

```
<mat-checkbox #c (click)="toggle(!c.checked)">Check me!</mat-checkbox>
```

- notice it's `!c.checked`, because by the time you click it, it's not checked yet.

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3kb8tw?file=app/checkbox-overview-example.html)

Comment: Since mat-checkbox supports `ngModel` we don't need a DOM reference variable `#c`

Comment: Yes! you are right. he has modified the question. But even though he don't want `ngModel`, DOM reference variable is still not needed. You can get it `$event` object through `(change)` event

Answer (score 4):

Use `[checked]` & `[value]` to bind the value, and pass the param in `(change)` event. I have created an example, check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anyw41?file=app/checkbox-configurable-example.html

Comment: I updated the answer too. It's working as you want. Please check the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anyw41?file=app/checkbox-configurable-example.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use the approach mentioned by [Kuncevič](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415078/kuncevi%c4%8d). To get the exact value you want to use something like this

```
<section *ngFor="let item of list">
  <mat-checkbox [checked]="item.value" (click)="toggle($event)">{{item.key}}</mat-checkbox>
</section>
```

And in the typescript use "event.source" to retrieve the value

```
toggle(event){
  console.log(event.source.value);
}
```

Comment: ERROR TypeError: "event.source is undefined"

Answer (score 4):

I solved it this way:

**HTML:**

```html
<mat-checkbox class="chklist" labelPosition="after" (change)="seleccionRubros($event)">
```

**TS:**

```js
public seleccionRubros(event: MatCheckboxChange) {

   if (!event.source.checked) {
      this.subRubrosSelec = [];
   }

};
```

Notice how I passed `$event` inside `seleccionRubros()` in the `(change)` event, and later on determined that on click, the checkbox was either checked or unchecked by reading `event.source.checked`.

As a clarification, I decided to specify the type of `event` but it's not actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible wihtout ngModel also :)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anyw41-zxrncz?file=app/checkbox-configurable-example.html

Comment: hahaha, sorry, did not see that all the other guys that already had posted answers...

Answer (score -1):

Pass **$event** to the function

```
<section *ngFor="let item of list">
  <mat-checkbox [checked]="item.value" (click)="toggle($event)">{{item.key}}</mat-checkbox>
</section>
```

You can get value in function from event object..

```
toggle(event){
  console.log(event)
}
```

I think it will be `event.value` (not sure on this. You can see in console)