# Angular checkboxes into array

Tags: javascript, angular

How to handle form input with checkboxes correctly? I have a form definition:

```
this.cargoSignupForm = new FormGroup({
        trucksToSelect: this.fb.array([])
      });
```

Submit function:

```
onSignupForCargo(cargoId: string) {
    this.cargosService.signupForCargo(
      cargoId,
      this.cargoSignupForm.value.trucksToSelect
    )
  }
```

and template:

```
<form [formGroup]="cargoSignupForm" (submit)="onSignupForCargo(cargo.id)" *ngIf="!isLoading">
                                      <div *ngFor="let truck of (trucksByCargoId.get(cargo.id)); let i = index">
                                        <mat-checkbox formControlName={{truck._id}} value={{truck._id}}>{{truck.regNumber}}</mat-checkbox>
                                      </div>
                                      <input type="submit" value="GO" class="button-basic">
                                    </form>
```

I want to export array of selected checkboxes(value must be truckId) to backend. Thank you for your time!

Comment: you should be using `this.cargoSignupForm.controls('trucksToSelect').value`

Answer (score 0):

I see some problems here:

1. trucksByCargoId.get(cargo.id) -- store this value in a const/var and pass that here .
2. You are taking truck._id as value for mat-checkbox but you want cargo.id as output.
   Please refer to this link
   [How to get the value from angular material checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53281709/how-to-get-the-value-from-angular-material-checkbox)

Comment: The value for checkbox is truckId. My mistake. I'll check the link and let you know