# Angular: How to map an array of 'mat-checkbox's to get strings associated with the checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-forms

To preface, I have found a solution that works for me in the situations I have tried it, but I am fairly new to javascript and RXJS and don't fully understand what the solution is doing so I can't be sure if it will work in every instance.

I am using reactive forms and have arrays of checkboxes, what I would like to do is get an array of all of the keys used to generate the checkboxes, but without any of the unchecked boxes. Ideally, I could use this to return additional values as well such as a user-readable string, but that is far from important as I can do that in a separate step fairly easily. I have come up with a few methods of my own, but they don't seem to be very robust or performant.

I would have replied on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50408431/11255299), but I lack the reputation.

This is the best solution I have found, which I would be totally happy to use, but I don't have much experience with RXJS or maps in javascript so I am not totally sure what it is doing:

```
this.controlNames = Object.keys(this.checkboxGroup.controls).map(_=>_); //This seems to just produce an object of control keys as properties and their value
this.selectedNames = this.checkboxGroup.valueChanges.pipe(map(v => Object.keys(v).filter(k => v[k]))); //Some sort of magic happens and an array is generated and contains only the keys whose values are 'true'
```

I have tried breaking that snippet apart and using console.log to test what it is doing in each step, but it really didn't give me much useful information. Any advice or or better ideas would be thoroughly appreciated, there seem to be a lot of conventions in javascript that people adhere to and it can be hard to sort through what is a convention and what is actually doing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a way to break it down and get a grip on it and want to post my explanation for anyone who comes looking.

---

In this part, it is just creating an iterable map of the 'checkboxGroup.controls' object. This could have been used to loop over in the template and make all of the checkboxes. Since my form structure is already generated from arrays of objects with known properties, I don't need this. The underscores aren't doing anything special here, people just like to use them for private variables.

```
this.controlNames = Object.keys(this.checkboxGroup.controls).map(_=>_);
```

For those who are new to arrow functions or some of the conventions of javascript, the code above is not quite, but essentially shorthand for this:

```
this.controlNames = [];
Object.keys(this.checkboxGroup.controls).forEach(function(key) {
  this.controlNames.push(key);
}
```

---

I have changed the short variables to longer ones to make them easier to understand in this second part. This maps the value changes observable as an iterable 'changesObj', retrieves the keys, and filters the keys by instances where the key has a true value. The code `filter(key => changesObj[key])` returns the key if the key is not null, undefined, or false.

```
this.selectedNames = this.checkboxGroup.valueChanges.pipe(map(changesObj => Object.keys(changesObj).filter(key => changesObj[key])));
```

This is essentially just shorthand for this:

```
function propNotFalse (changes, prop) {
  return changes[prop] == true;
}

this.selectedNames = this.alternateFilter = Object.keys(this.checkboxGroup.valueChanges).filter(this.propNotFalse.bind(null, this.checkboxGroup.valueChanges));
```